# Use of count in where statement sql

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have `N` transactions with `camera_id = 6` and i want to sample every `N // 100` transaction.
I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.id from (
    SELECT id, camera_id, start_ts, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_ts) AS rownum
    FROM transactions
    WHERE camera_id = 6  
) as t
where t.rownum % (N / 100) = 1
order by t.start_ts
```

How can i change it so i don't need additional query for determining `N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Untested*

Does the following work for you - add a windowed count in addition to your Rownumber and use that:

```
SELECT t.id from (
    SELECT id, camera_id, start_ts, 
            Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY start_ts) AS rownum,
            Count(*) over() Qty
    FROM transactions
    WHERE camera_id = 6  
) as t
where t.rownum % (Qty / 100) = 1
order by t.start_ts
```